# Cakephp scaffold, leave it or remove it?

Tags: cakephp, scaffold

What's the best way to handle the scaffold when it comes to the deployment stage?

Leave it there? But then what's the best way to protect the access of it?

Remove it? But then I need another system to access all the data, right?

How do people usually handle the scaffold in CakePHP which is very useful in the building process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people would not use scaffold anymore when getting close to deployment.
That is where "bake" comes into play.

You usually only scaffold while still changing the database structure heavily.
As soon as it gets stable you use custom bake templates to bake your views to real files.
I actually never use scaffolding as bake has way more advantages (such as full customization of the template output.
And rebaking is not that big of a deal. It is pretty fast to achieve.

Comment: Agree, just be sure to back-up your project before baking in case the bake didn't generate the desired result. Even better, use a version control system if you're not already doing so, so that you can roll back the changes. Scaffold is not meant for production environments, it's also bad for performance because it is 'generating' the code on-the-fly, having to inspect your database structure with each request/page views

Comment: I also agree, with one exception.  You could use scaffolding for the admin section, if will only be used occasionally by a couple developers.  However, once you're ready to start pushing admin functions to some of your users, you need to build them properly.